# Cloning tbody breaks table columns

Tags: jquery, html

Got simple table, where I'm trying to clone and insert tbody element multiple times.

Issue: cloned cells don't align with the defined columns properly. (see jsfiddle)

Not sure what's going on here. I must use tables and tbody.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

```
<table class='assignees-form table border none'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Assignee</th>
      <th>Start</th>
      <th>Due</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class='assignee-template'>
    <tr>
      <td class='name'>Name</td>
      <td class='start'>Start</td>
      <td class='due'>Due</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr class='assignees-controls'>
      <td><button class='add-button'>Add row</button></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>

$('.add-button').click(function() {
    $('.assignee-template').clone()
            .removeClass('assignee-template').addClass('assignee')
            .insertBefore('.assignees-controls')
            .show();
});
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/u66tL6pp/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are inserting cloned `tbody` inside the `tfoot`(before the `tr` inside `tfoot`), instead insert `tbody` before `tfoot`.

```
$('.add-button').click(function() {
    $('.assignee-template').clone()
            .removeClass('assignee-template').addClass('assignee')
            .insertBefore('tfoot')
            .show();
});
```

```js
$('.add-button').click(function() {
  $('.assignee-template').clone()
    .removeClass('assignee-template').addClass('assignee')
    .insertBefore('tfoot')
    .show();
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 50%
}
td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class='assignees-form table border none'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Assignee</th>
      <th>Start</th>
      <th>Due</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class='assignee-template'>
    <tr>
      <td class='name'>Name</td>
      <td class='start'>Start</td>
      <td class='due'>Due</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr class='assignees-controls'>
      <td>
        <button class='add-button'>Add row</button>
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

**FYI :** Also why should you need to clone the entire `tbody`? instead just clone the first tr and append it to the `tbody`.

Comment: How did i miss that part? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AlexG : sometimes we may miss something...... we all are human being... it may happen .. LOL :D

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.add-button').click(function() {
  $('.table tbody').append($('.assignee-template tr').clone())//clone tr only
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class='assignees-form table border none'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Assignee</th>
      <th>Start</th>
      <th>Due</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class='assignee-template'>
    <tr>
      <td class='name'>Name</td>
      <td class='start'>Start</td>
      <td class='due'>Due</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr class='assignees-controls'>
      <td>
        <button class='add-button'>Add row</button>
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

1. Clone tr only.
2. Use [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

> Description: Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element in the set of matched elements.